# How to use worksheetfunction.large with array?

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet-function

I need your help.. :(

I would like to use the worksheetfunction.large, where the input-array is a stored array. But I simply can't get it to work.. :( I get errors all the time stating: "Unable to get the Large property of the WorksheetFunction Class" - proberbly because my arraystatement is wrong. In my new MLArray I have arround 1800 lines, with unique numbers (decimals) between 0 and 1 - and I need to know, what the limit is, to get in to top 100 - therefore the .Large function..

Can anyone give me the hint, on how to use the array, so I can get the MLFixpoint value at the end of my code..?

Best regards
/Kenneth

```
Dim arr1 As Variant
Dim NewArray As Variant
Dim MLArray As Variant

'Arr1 is from another workbook with 100000 rows
arr1 = .Range("A1:BM" & tempUsedRangeRow).Value

'Here I select only the rows in my array, that has R62 as condition - and then the other workbook is closed, but my array is preserved
NewArray = ArrayRemoveRow(arr1, "aktafd", "R62", 3, True)

'Here I state the new onedimensional array, that I believe I have to use in my worksheet formula
ReDim MLArray(UBound(NewArray, 1))

'I run through the "newArray"
For ml = 1 To UBound(NewArray)
    MLArray(ml) = NewArray(ml, RykkerIndex)
Next ml
    
    
'As Excel formula
'MLfixpoint = Application.WorksheetFunction.Large("AU:AU", 100)
    
    
'My problem
'MLfixpoint = Application.WorksheetFunction.Large(MLArray(0), MLArray(allRows), DailyMLCapacity)
```

Comment: Do you need to return a 100th rank from the largest value down? If you try `Application.WorksheetFunction.Large("AU:AU", 1)` does the function return anything?

Comment: I cannot use it with "AU:AU" because the array is only stored in the memory at the moment where I call my code.. But if i paste the array manually into excel, and uses the function at last, then it works - but I have several steps I need to go through before I can paste it, and in theese steps, I need the MLFixPoint value

Comment: Anyhow, `WorksheetFunction.Large` needs a range/array as parameter. So, it should be used as `Application.WorksheetFunction.Large(Range("AU:AU"), 100)`, or `Application.WorksheetFunction.Large(myArr, 100)` after placing the range in `myArr` array...

Comment: In my last line of the code I try to use your reference myArr (in my code MLArray) but it keeps failing.
MLfixpoint = Application.WorksheetFunction.Large(MLArray, 100)

Comment: Did you try it as `Application.WorksheetFunction.Large(MLArray, 1)`. This function returns such an error when there are less than second parameter different values...

Comment: Yes i have tried that as well - and same error.. It seems to be the array that causes the problem, but I can't figure why.. If I try to debug the array eg. to a Notepadfile, I can see the input from the different places in the array, so it is not empty

Comment: You should also post the function `ArrayRemoveRow` code... Then, are you sure that there are no errors in the range to be processed?

Comment: Bang - you nailed it, there was one error in the array (and the MLFixpoint was dim'ed as a long, but should have been a Double. Thanx for your help :o)